# Can we start developing using Apple id and later use my client's Developer Program license to publish to Itunes

Tags: ios, xcode

I a newbie in IOS App development . My question my be naive please bear with me .After I tried to get some knowledge on how to develop and deploy an IOS app finally got bit confused.

I have created an AppleID and using the same with XCode. I have a client who wants to develop an App for their company. After a bit of research I understand that we need a Developer License for us to use a real Iphone device to test instead of a simulator.

My question is whether can I start with my AppleID and without enrolling to the Developer Program and later use my Client's developer programme license when its required APP submission to store. Will that be any issue for code signing , bundle id creation etc. since the Apple id of my client will be different one and the associated Programme license too.

One more thing is that my Client haven't enrolled to the Developer Program yet, so I would like to use another developer program of my friend's since I would need to have the app tested in a real device ( not a jailbroken one ) instead of a simulator. So once the client enrolls successfully to the Developer Program I'm looking to switch to it. Does this pose an issue?

Please advise.

Comment: Yes . After you get client's Apple Id add client's app id and certificates in your xcode - > preference-> account and change bundle identifier in your target.

Comment: Thanks alot Mihir Oza

Comment: It's my pleasure. Need any other help ask me. I will try my best to  solve your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try new Feature of Xcode 7. They provide testing on real phone without developer account you only have to sign in both xcode  and your iphone with same Apple acount and you ready to test you app on your iphone without developer account

Check out this link

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: Thanks Vivek. I tried to explore that option but seems to be Xcode 7 is in Beta version . So it wont allow to publish later it using beta version .

Comment: Xcode 7.1 final version already released but i suggest to use Xcode 7.